# Explanation of the model object in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

```
@Controller
public class GreetingController {

    @GetMapping("/greeting")
    public String greeting(HttpServletRequest request, Model model) {

        String name = request.getParameter("name");
        model.addAttribute("name", name);

        return "greeting";
    }
}
```

What does the `Model` do? Is this essentially the context variables that are passed to the "greeting.html" file? Is the only use of it `addAttributes` that will then be passed to the HTML template? Where could I read more about what Model does and how it should be used?

Comment: This seems to be asking for [a tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this makes it off topic. But here's [a tutorial](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view) about all the model things...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you see the documentation of [`Model`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/ui/Model.html)?

> Java-5-specific interface that defines a holder for model attributes. Primarily designed for adding attributes to the model. Allows for accessing the overall model as a `java.util.Map`.

`Model` is an essential part of [MVC pattern](https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/) which is widely used in Spring. As you have said, a `Model` is a holder of the context data passed by a `Controller` to be displayed on a `View`.

You can use only one `Model` which contains more data distinct with a unique key because the `Model` is based on the [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) - as the documentation says..

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes, that's what the `Model` do. But you can merge two `Model` objects parameters too, so this makes things easier.

More than it, you use `ModelMap` and `ModelandView` objects. If you want to read about it, take a look at: [Spring MVC Model Map Model](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-model-model-map-model-view)

Answer (score 0):

In this case the model is used to pass data to the view. For example you are using JSP, or some template like thymeleaf, you can put thigns that you want to be displayed in the model, and you will be able to access it from those views.

You could read more about that in the [Spring MVC Reference](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#spring-web)