# Why a Spring MVC model attribute is not (always) accessible in the model?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

After reading questions and answers on the topic, such as

[Explanation of the model object in Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51143616/explanation-of-the-model-object-in-spring)

as well as the official documentation of Spring MVC, I still wonder why is a Spring MVC model attribute is not (always) accessible in the model. For example in my code below you can see a Spring MVC Controller class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/student")
public class StudentController {

    @RequestMapping("/showForm")
    public String showForm(Model model) {
        Student theStudent = new Student();
        model.addAttribute("student", theStudent);
        return "student-form";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processFormV1")
    public String processStudentInput(@ModelAttribute("student") Student student, Model model) {

        System.out.println("student.getFirstName(): " + student.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("student.getLastName(): " + student.getLastName());

        return "student-confirmation";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/processFormV2")
    public String processStudentInput(Model model) {

        Student student = (Student) model.getAttribute("student");
        System.out.println("student.getFirstName(): " + student.getFirstName());
        System.out.println("student.getLastName(): " + student.getLastName());

        return "student-confirmation";

}
}
```

and this is my view, student-form.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Student Form</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form:form action="processFormV2" modelAttribute="student">
        First name: <form:input path="firstName"/>
        <br>
        Last name: <form:input path="lastName"/>
        
        <input type = "submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

Now, when the form action is `processFormV2` and I submit the form, the line below gives me a null for the student:

```
Student student = (Student) model.getAttribute("student");
```

However, when I change the form action to processFormV1 and I submit the form, in the controller method I am able to read the provided values for both names of the Student correctly.

1. Why is this so?
2. What is the scope of the values in a Model? Request or Session? From what I have, I always thought the scope is session. Is that right?

Comment: The model only lives for a single request not session so no you are wrong. So values in the model are always request scoped. The `processFormV1` creates a new model attribute for `Student` because it is indicated (with the `@ModelAttribute`) to do so.

Comment: @M.Deinum, OK, but in the view, we also have  modelAttribute="student", so why is this not enough to put a student  object in the Model?

Comment: Because that is for reading and not writing, also how should you derive a type from just a name when submitting?

Comment: @M.Deinum "how should you derive the type..." - from the Student class, which already defines both fields firstName and familyName of type String.

Comment: How? When submitting the form the only thing known is the name, not the type.